# With bigquery variable @DS_END_DATE I am losing 24 hours

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

So, there is a piece of query from bigquery to google data studio report:

```
WHERE 
   creation_date IN (NULL, '1970-01-01T00:00:00') OR 
   creation_date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND
   PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```

And `@DS_END_DATE` helps users select date range in GDS report. However, when filtering data, I am missing last day. For example, if `@DS_END_DATE` is `'2022-10-20'`, I can't find rows with `creation_date = '2022-10-20T14:03:08'` in report. But report contains all data till `'2022-10-20'`

How can I query bigquery to get all stuff from @DS_END_DATE like it is `'2022-10-20T23:59:59'` ?

P.S. Yeah, there were some troubles first time, so I am using `creation_date IN (NULL, '1970-01-01T00:00:00')` to identify deleted IDs, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When BigQuery is doing the comparison it is normalizing the data types and casting your provided date as a timestamp.  When it does this conversion it looks like `2022-10-20 00:00:00 UTC`.  Given that you can see why it is dropping things on `2022-10-20`.
To alleviate this you can do something like:

```
select 
creation_date
from sample_data
where cast(creation_date as date) between '2022-10-19' and '2022-10-20'
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work! I was trying to add some string `'23:59:59'` but your solution much more better! And I'm not skilled at all in sql ))